# convert timestamp to date

Tags: java, android, datetime

I'm getting the date from an sms message in android as a time stamp in seconds or milliseconds from epoch.I need to display it as standard date and time using java.

```
int date      = (cursor.getColumnIndex(SmsReceiver.DATE));
```

this returns some number like 1308114404722.

what is the process to use this number and display as current date

Comment: also on using  Date converted = new Date(date); it display Thu Jan 01 5:30 ...1970 etc

Comment: the int date does not hold the milliseconds value displayed in the question, it just has the column index. To get that seconds value i had to use String date2 = cursor.getString(date); now this string holds the 130811.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int date = ...
Date dateObj = new Date(date);
```

To format a `Date` object, use for example `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String text = df.format(dateObj);
```

Also, you should store number-of-milliseconds-since-epoch values in a `long`, not in an `int`, because an `int` is not large enough. (In fact, the number 1308114404722 doesn't even fit in a 32-bit `int`).

Comment: even after using long i still get 01-01-1970

Comment: @technocrat are you sure the number is a number of *milliseconds* since 01-01-1970? or is it maybe a number of *seconds* since 01-01-1970? (in that case, multiply it by 1000).

Comment: Dude, as i have commented on my question, i was not getting the millis in the date values. After calling cursor.getString(date) it returns the millis and i sorted out the rest.. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the int issue. I was receiving the timestamp as an int and I was getting weird results all the time.

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm dd.MM.yyyy");
Date date = new Date(1308114404722);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like that

```
public static java.util.Date toDate(java.sql.Timestamp timestamp) {
long millisec = timestamp.getTime() + (timestamp.getNanos() / 1000000);
return new Date(millisec);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getInstance();
String dateStr = df.format( new Date( date ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that this is Epoch Timestamp to convert it to human readable form use

```
int date = (cursor.getColumnIndex(SmsReceiver.DATE));
String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date (date*1000));
```

hopefully this will work as on converting this value: **1308114404722**

the time comes to be **Wed, 15 Jun 2011 05:06:44 GMT**

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert the timestamp. I've multiplied by 1000 because some people usually divide by 1000 when saving the timestamp. You can try with the 1000 or without.

```
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
    Date date = new Date();
    date.setTime(Long.parseLong(YOUR_INT_OR_LONG_TIMESTAMP)*1000);
    String readableTime = format.format(date);
```

You can explore more formatting options in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score -1):

To convert the unix time stamp that you are getting to a normal date use this snippet of code:

//date here should be a long

long date      = (cursor.getColumnIndex(SmsReceiver.DATE));

String standardDate=DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date(date);