# Convert timestamp to date in Android?

Tags: android

I am implementing one android application in which I want to convert timestamp to date but I could not get success.
I have tried below things.
Please check it if I am doing something wrong.

I am passing this value :

```
myTimestamp=1328015914;
DateFormat.getDateFormat(mContext).format(new Date(myTimestamp * 1000));
```

It returns `11/1/1970` but its wrong.

Please help me for this query.

Thanks
Manthan Dalal

Comment: which package you are importing to use above line of code ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert timestamp to date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369731/convert-timestamp-to-date)

Answer (score 4):

You might need to specify the time zone. This is the method i use.

```
private String getDate(long timeStamp){
    DateFormat objFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    objFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone));

    Calendar objCalendar =    
            Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone));
    objCalendar.setTimeInMillis(timeStamp*1000);//edit
    String result = objFormatter.format(objCalendar.getTime());
    objCalendar.clear();
    return result;         
}
```

Comment: Great answer , but you have first to convert the tim to Milliseconds so it's should            `code` objCalendar.setTimeInMillis(timeStamp);

Answer (score 0):

hey how about making a method that will convert your timestamp to date. like -

```
public static Date convertTimestampToDate(Timestamp timestamp) {
    return new Date(timestamp.getTime());
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND,     
tz.getOffset(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
java.util.Date currenTimeZone=new java.util.Date((long)1379487711*1000);
Toast.makeText(TimeStampChkActivity.this, sdf.format(currenTimeZone), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```